# how I replace first row value after rbind the col names to the data.frame

Tags: r

I am trying to build a table.
Here is what it looks like now: I rbind colnames to the dataset.
[image]

Is it a way to replace first row value to Grade # to "#" ,and Grade #.1 to "%"?

the final table should looks like
[image]

sample data can be build using following codes:

```
df<-structure(list(AEDECOD = c("Alanine aminotransferase increased", 
"Aspartate aminotransferase increased"), `Grade 1` = 0:1, `Grade 1.1` = c("(0.00 %)", 
"(5.26 %)"), `Grade 2` = 1:0, `Grade 2.1` = c("(5.26 %)", "(0.00 %)"
), `Grade 3` = c(0L, 0L), `Grade 3.1` = c("(0.00 %)", "(0.00 %)"
), Total = c(1, 1), Total.1 = c("(5.26 %)", "(5.26 %)")), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex to identify the columns and use it in `across` :

```
library(dplyr)


df %>%
  mutate(across(matches('(Grade \\d+$)|(^Total$)'), replace, 1, '#'), 
         across(matches('(Grade \\d+\\.\\d+$)|(Total\\.\\d+)'), replace, 1, '%'))

#                              AEDECOD Grade 1 Grade 1.1 Grade 2
#1                              AEDECOD       #         %       #
#2   Alanine aminotransferase increased       0  (0.00 %)       1
#3 Aspartate aminotransferase increased       1  (5.26 %)       0

#  Grade 2.1 Grade 3 Grade 3.1 Total  Total.1
#1         %       #         %     #        %
#2  (5.26 %)       0  (0.00 %)     1 (5.26 %)
#3  (0.00 %)       0  (0.00 %)     1 (5.26 %)
```

**data**

```
df <- rbind(names(df),df)
```

Answer (score 1):

this will also do

```
df <- rbind(colnames(df), df)

library(stringr)
df[1,] <- str_replace(str_replace(df[1,], "(Grade \\d+$)|(^Total$)", "#"), "(Grade \\d+\\.\\d+$)|(Total\\.\\d+)", "%")

> df
                               AEDECOD Grade 1 Grade 1.1 Grade 2 Grade 2.1 Grade 3 Grade 3.1 Total  Total.1
1                              AEDECOD       #         %       #         %       #         %     #        %
2   Alanine aminotransferase increased       0  (0.00 %)       1  (5.26 %)       0  (0.00 %)     1 (5.26 %)
3 Aspartate aminotransferase increased       1  (5.26 %)       0  (0.00 %)       0  (0.00 %)     1 (5.26 %
```